# "First run" after update on windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

So, I've being searching a lot on stackoverflow and could only find a way to determine if my app is running for the first time on the users device.

[Is there a "first run" flag in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609412/is-there-a-first-run-flag-in-wp7)

Question is: I'm going to post a update for my app and would like that the user, after updates and runs it, receive a little popup with what's new on the app, but just the first time he runs after the update.

Is something like this possible?

It would be important to maintain the "first run", and include the "first run after update"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is as simple as storing a flag in a datastore(DB or file) in your app. If the flag is set then it's already been run. If it's not set then show the popup and then set the flag. There's no need to rely on any sort of operating system behaviour to provide this.

**Edit:** I notice you distinguish between 'first run' and 'first run after update'. If you wanted this granularity then simply store a version number along with the flag. If you don't have that version number already flagged then it's the first run since the update.