# Windows Phone - C# - First Time Run

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Is there any way to find out if the application has run for the first time; and if so, how do I access it?

Comment: There are lots of ways of guessing, but for a truly motivated user they can delete whatever you're using to indicate that the program has run before, making it *appear* to run for the first time when that's not the case, or the opposite (faking an indicator that it has run before when it hasn't).  Are you trying to defend against such malicious behavior, or are you assuming that your users aren't actively trying to defeat this particular mechanism.

Comment: That the users aren't trying to exploit this malicious technique, as the majority of users won't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a built in feature for this (that I know of), but you could use this bit of code.  [Is there a "first run" flag in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609412/is-there-a-first-run-flag-in-wp7)

Essentially you just want to use `IsolatedStorage` and write something there such as a boolean and check that each time the app is ran.

Comment: Also consider adding version information to the first-run flag, such that you could determine in later versions what new features you'd want to showcase on first run.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this on iPhone and Android to display a "Please rate us.." dialog on the first run. A simple solution for both cases, and Windows Phone as well, is to write out a file on the first run. Check for it when the app starts, if it's not there, you know it's the first run.