# how to know whether the windows phone app is run for the first time

Tags: c#, windows-phone

How can I detect whether my Windows Phone App is run for the first time?
Do we have any method which I can look in?

Here is the Scenario:

I'm building an App which will ask for few details bu the user if he or she is opening the App for the first time. Now when someone tries to open the App for the next time it should not show the same questioning details page which came at the beginning, Instead should show another page.

So, my question is How do I detect whether the App is opened for the first time or not? What is the logic for that? 
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer on SO: 
It writes a file to the iso storage if the app is run, so that way you know if the file exists.

[Is there a "first run" flag in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609412/is-there-a-first-run-flag-in-wp7)

Note: The solution is for windows phone 7, but my guess is that it should work with Win8 or win8.1